# how to get lat/lng info for clicks in leaflet map in an angular ui

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, leaflet

I'm building a pretty basic web app with Angular.js and Leaflet.

I'm trying to get the lat/lng info from the clicks on the map and i'm having trouble finding any docs on integrating the event handlers from Leaflet into Angular.

if anyone could point me in the right direction, i'd be stoked.

the code below:

```
app.controller("eventcrtl", [ '$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMap.click', function(event){
      console.log(event.latlng);
    });
}]);
```

doesn't work

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To handle events, first define an events object on your scope...

```
angular.extend($scope, {
    events: {
      map: {
        enable: ['click', 'drag', 'blur', 'touchstart'],
        logic: 'emit'
      }
    },
    ...
```

and add it to your leaflet element.

```
<leaflet event-broadcast="events"></leaflet>
```

Then, you can access latitude and longitude inside the args parameter of the click handler:

```
$scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMap.click', function(event, args){
    console.log(args.leafletEvent.latlng);
});
```

Here is a working demo:  http://plnkr.co/PxRDhz6S5Svsg9FG4VRk

Comment: this is perfect. thank you! is there a reason to extend $scope, vs assigning it directly?

Comment: Not that I know of.  That's just how the original demo I forked from was written.

Comment: In 0.7.6 at least, events appear to be enabled by default so no need for the `event-broadcast` attribute (although probably a good idea to define the events you want explicitly).